# How to make text appear near the bottom of an image in React Native?

Tags: image, react-native, styling

I'm having some trouble, making the text appear near the bottom of the image unlike 
[here in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3t8w.png). I've done a lot, including playing around with the margins, fiddling around with the aspectRatio, resizeMode, and also height and width to no avail. I also tried searching here, and the solutions presented were for resizing images but not to make some text appear directly at the bottom of the image.  Thanks for anyone that would help.

Comment: just remove flex:1 in img style and apply width and height to it. it may work.

Comment: if @PatelDhara solution not works for you, please include your code to check

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I tried a lot of combinations already and been stuck for hours. So thank you again.